# How to disable mobile redirect on a website I don't control?

Tags: redirect, mobile, web-applications, web

I created a website/webapp that displays information for my university's dining halls in a more mobile-friendly format than what the vendor currently has. The page has a button that takes you to the official vendor's website showing you the current menu for the relevant dining hall (why remake what already works, right?). The problem is that if you try to access this from a mobile device, it'll do something like this:

[image: XKCD 869]

Where it redirects you to the main page of the mobile website instead of the page I want. I'd like to disable the mobile redirect somehow, but I don't own the website. I couldn't find a way to do this, and all the questions out there are asking how to do it in reverse. Any ideas? Is it possible to trick the website into thinking my device is a desktop device?

If anyone wants code, please let me know, but I think this question is general enough that it doesn't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround was to link directly to the mobile version of the website I wanted to access... No redirect, no problem.